# Nhibernate/C# - Set Nhibernate to decode all text inputs before SQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The site I am working on is mostly secure data entry and I am using the following workflow:

1. User Enters Text
2. JS encodeURI(text)
3. Ajax to C#
4. C# calls nHibernate method
5. nHiberate executes SQL
6. returns to C#
7. returns to JS
8. JS decodeURI

I am wondering if it is possible to set nHibernate to decode all text fields before sending them to SQL without having to manually decode  every single text field. I would like to do this because the reports I generate in SQL contain the encoding and is unreadable.

Again, I am looking for some sort of global setting for nHiberate to decode all text fields before sending them to SQL.

Or perhaps a way to decode before generating the report?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is not dealing with sq-server at all, so I removed the tag. please use tags properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom type that encode/decode when you set/get the property.  You'll need to derive from IUserType and register your type with NHibernate.  Here's an example en encrypted string

https://gist.github.com/jasondentler/1170933#file-encryptedstring-cs

Alternatively you could write  EventListeners and do your encode/decode there.

Here's the documentation on EventListeners

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html

If I were you I'd go down the Custom type route.  It's less code to maintain and is more of what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!